# Passando dados para um modal

Tags: angular, ionic

Estou tentando passar dados para um modal.
Acredito que eu tenha conseguido a primeira parte, pois no console do chrome vejo que recebi esses dados, porém não sei o que está errado, que não estou conseguindo visualizar eles na tela.

Home Html

```
 <button ion-button small class="button-select" (click)="openFiltrosModal()">Filtros</button>
```

Home TS

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
regioes: Regiao[];

constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController, private nav: NavController, 
private videoPlayer: VideoPlayer, private payPal: PayPal, public viewCtrl: 
ViewController,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
public db: DatabaseProvider, private toastCtrl: ToastController)

 openFiltrosModal() {
this.openModal('FiltrosModalPage');
}
openModal(pageName) {

this.modalCtrl.create(pageName, {'val': this.regioes}, { cssClass: 'inset- 
modal' })
              .present();
}
```

MODAL TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, NavController, ViewController, IonicPage } from 'ionic- 
angular';
import { Regiao } from '../../models/regiao';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-filtros-modal',
templateUrl: 'filtros-modal.html'
})
export class FiltrosModalPage {
regioes: Regiao;
myParam: string;

constructor(public navParams: NavParams, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
console.log(navParams.get('val'));
this.myParam = navParams.get('myParam');
}

dismiss() {
this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}

}
```

MODAL HTML

```
  <ion-select interface="popover" (ionChange)="selecionaregiao($event)" 
  [(ngModel)]="regiao">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let regiao of regioes" [value]="regiao.id"> 
  {{regiao.nom_regiao}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

[image: img]

Alguém pode me ajudar nisso? não sei se estou fazendo errado ou esquecendo de algo

Comment: mostra o erro do console

Comment: @JulioHenrique não recebo nenhum erro ao abrir o Modal. apenas no console recebo os dados como postei na imagem acima. Porém quando clico no Select na página, nao tem nenhum resultado. Mas se eu colocar apenas: {{regiao.nom_regiao}} que é o que eu uso na page Home e funciona, ai da o erro: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom_regiao' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (FiltrosModalPage.html:23)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer]

Comment: Onde você inicializa "regioes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O HTML está buscando a variável `regioes` e não a `myParams`. 
No constructor, altere `this.myParam = navParams.get('myParam');` para `this.regioes = navParams.get('myParam');`.